# Wordpress. Добавление класса к подменю, в зависимости от класса родительского элемента

Tags: wordpress

Прошу помощи. Мне нужно добавить дополнительный класс в подменю (тэг ul)? в зависимости от того, если конкретный класс в родительском меню (тэг li). Если у родителя (тэг li) присутствует класс 'position-static', то только в этом случае, добавить в дочернему элементу (тэг ul) класс 'submenu-nav-mega column-3'. Ну или по другому, если у родителя скажем ID135, то добавить в дочернему элементу (тэг ul) класс 'submenu-nav-mega column-3'. Я голову сломал - у меня не получилось.
Должно получится

```html
<li class="has-submenu position-static"><a href="#/"><span>Shop</span></a>
                    <ul class="submenu-nav submenu-nav-mega column-3">
                      <li class="mega-menu-item"><a href="#/" class="mega-title"><span>Shop Layout</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="shop-three-columns.html"><span>Shop 3 Column</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop-four-columns.html"><span>Shop 4 Column</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop.html"><span>Shop Left Sidebar</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop-right-sidebar.html"><span>Shop Right Sidebar</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="mega-menu-item"><a href="#/" class="mega-title"><span>Single Product</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="single-normal-product.html"><span>Single Product Normal</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="single-product.html"><span>Single Product Variable</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="single-group-product.html"><span>Single Product Group</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="single-affiliate-product.html"><span>Single Product Affiliate</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="mega-menu-item"><a href="#/" class="mega-title"><span>Others Pages</span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="shop-cart.html"><span>Shopping Cart</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop-checkout.html"><span>Checkout</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop-wishlist.html"><span>Wishlist</span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="shop-compare.html"><span>Compare</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
```